# Using Alternatives for Document.cshtml in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, .net, razor, orchardcms

I am currently working on a website that requires the ability to overwrite the document.cshtml file so that I can apply a specific CSS-class based on the user's current location.

I have attempted to use URL alternatives such as:

- **Document.cshtml**
- **Document-url-AreaA.cshtml**
- **Document-url-AreaB.cshtml**
- **Document.url-AreaC.cshtml**

however it appears that all of them use the Document.cshtml as opposed to using one based on the URL. I could easily understand that this is the intended purpose, however I was wondering if it would be possible to implement the functionality above.

---

## Update

I believe that I may have made some progress in this area, as opposed to using URL alternatives, and simply adding a field on the Model (for the document) to simply pull the current "Area" of the site and apply that class to the body.

*(Within document.cshtml)*

```
@using Orchard.Mvc.Html;
@using Orchard.UI.Resources;
@{
    RegisterLink(new LinkEntry {Type = "image/x-icon", ...});

    string title = Convert.ToString(Model.Title);
    string siteName = Convert.ToString(WorkContext.CurrentSite.SiteName);

     //Pull the Area here
    string area = Model.DesignatedAreaField;
}
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" class="static @Html.ClassForPage()"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@Html.Title(title, siteName)</title> 
    @Display(Model.Head)
</head> 
<body class='@area'>
//Body goes here
@Display(Model.Body)
@Display(Model.Tail)
</body>
</html>
```

I believe that this may be an easier solution than the one previously suggested. However, I am wondering what the easiest method of actually placing a field that I could access from the Model of the Document, would be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Document.cshtml is a wrapper for the Layout shape. Wrappers don't support alternates. The only way to replace the document.cshtml template selectively is to remove the existing wrapper from the wrappers collection on the metadata of the layout shape and add your own.

But wait... I can't think of any good reason why you'd want to do that. What's in document.cshtml is boilerplate HTML that should be the same across the site. The solution described in your update is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. I have attempted several attempts at setting the 'area' mentioned above, however I was unable to get it to work. Is there anything that I might be missing? I added a Content Field to the Page and attempted to set it as Layout.FieldName and attempted to access it by using string = Layout.FieldName, but wasn't able to access it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Right, `@area` is not going to cut it. `@Model.FieldName` would work, provided you set `Layout.FieldName="something"` from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You could also move the `<body>` tag into Layout.cshtml, and then use URL alternates of Layout.cshtml to set the `<body>'s` class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this post: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/12/14/switching-the-layout-in-orchard-cms.aspx. It shows how you can dynamically add your own alternates, but the same approach could work to add properties to the model or layout based on geolocation.

I think you can define some code within OnResultExecuting() to dynamically add a property to the Model class. Since it's of type dynamic you should just be able to set it, nothing special needed.